# Can an airline, such as Iberia, see my recent flight history with Vueling?

Tags: air-travel

I am flying with Vueling from A to B, two days after I am flying with Iberia from B to C. I want to know if Iberia will have access to my previous flight from A to B with Veuling.

Iberia and Vueling is the 'low-cost' brand with Iberia and most of its flights are code-shared with the company. Where flight from A to B is Vueling and code-shared with Iberia, flight from B to C is only Iberia.

Comment: I don't have the knowledge to answer this question, but I'm curious why you're asking. What does it matter whether Iberia know you flew with Vueling a few days earlier?

Comment: Due to current covid travel restrictions.

Comment: Isn't a Spanish company bound by GDPR, the EU's data protection law?

Comment: @WeatherVane what would that mean, in relation to this situation?

Comment: It suggests you are trying to dodge Covid-19 restrictions, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @daisy So you're trying to circumvent legal restrictions in place and want to lie to Iberia and to the authorities about where you have been recently? I would have thought 2 million dead are a reason good enough to respect the restrictions in place, they are here for a good reason.

Comment: As far as I know, data protection laws do allow a business to share data with their partners, for internal purposes, and for detection and prevention of fraud, etc.

Comment: Why the downvotes? The question seems fair enough - regardless of the context.

Answer (score 3):

Hard to know for sure, but quite likely the answer is yes. Both airlines are owned by the same parent company and are likely sharing some of the backend infrastructure.

Iberia has certainly access to some data about a code share flight but it's hard to say if that also includes the full passenger list even if Vueling sold the ticket.

So the answer to "can they" is probably "yes". That doesn't man that they "will" or if it's legal for them to do so. For the latter, you would have to read the terms and conditions of both tickets (and that you agreed to) and also read the contract of carriage  of both airlines.